# Exec statement python

Tags: python

How do I execute a statement dynamically in Python?

For ex: assume the value x contains the following expression, (a+b)/2,

```
a = 1
b = 3
x = (a+b)/2
```

The value for x will be from a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want `eval`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

a = 1
b = 3
x = "(a+b)/2"
print eval(x)
```

But it's usually considered a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice) (click [here](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/03/24/on-principle/) for a more elaborate and funnier explanation)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
a = 1
b = 3
x = '(a+b)/2'

print eval(x)
```

Note that the value for `x` is enclosed in quotes as `eval` requires a string or code object.

Also, perhaps read [this](http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html) to make sure you use it safely (as that can often be a concern and I'm not going to pretend to be an expert in its flaws :) ).

Comment: There is no way to use eval safely, that article is wrong.  Read [Eval Really is Dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) for details.

Comment: Haha, yeah, I have actually completely avoided it solely due to reading others' comments on this site (and will continue to do so :) ).

Answer (score 0):

Although python has both "exec()" and "eval()", I believe you wan to use the latter in this case:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 3
>>> x = "(a + b)/2"
>>> eval(x)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval, as in

```
eval(x)
```

Actually you can use

```
x=eval('(a+b)/2')
```

to get the result (eval will return the result of the computation in this case).